# How to process property file values during server start up in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this entry in application.properties of my spring boot app:

`myapp.urls = url1,url2,url3`

In a method in my component, I am creating an array like below:

`String myArray[] = properties.getmyAppUrls().split(",");`

I want this array creation logic execute only once.  I know we can achieve this using post construct.  Is there any other way we could achieve this like during server start up?

I want this array constructed reading from a properties file during server start up and i want to use this in my component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spring EL to do the job:

```
@Value("#{'${myapp.urls}'.split(',')}") 
private List<String> myAppUrls;
```

I'd recommend to move this to a `Configuration` class, then you can autowire it everywhere you need it.

Comment: Spring is smart enough to make conversions on its own, you can simply use: `@Value("${myapp.urls}") List<String> urls`.

Comment: @DirkDeyne -- you are right this worked too.  And this is a bit easier thanks!